# Data Integrity monitoring tool

Tags: mysql, monitoring

We have an MYSQL database and we are having some incoherent data (mostly added manually). These incoherence cannot be handled as a constraint to the database as they are more business oriented.

To handle this, we run few queries then and there manually to detect these cases. I am curious to know if there are tools that could do this regularly. Monitor the data by regularly running these queries and send us notification etc.
Please suggest. Thank you

Comment: I you have working code and want to run it regularly then an MYSQL EVENT would seem to be the way to go..

Comment: The queries can be executed regularly using Event Scheduler. They may output the results to some pre-defined files. Then some external scheduler may read these files and send needed notifications.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will look into Event scheduler further. But I am really looking for some easily configurable tool if something like this exists

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.